# Wordpress. Некоректний вывод символов "-" и "&" из заголовков статьи

Tags: php, wordpress

Идея такая стоит, что каждый 1 символ слова после пробела надо красить в другой цвет.

К примеру должно быть вот так: "**J**ETPEEL™ **M**EDICAL **A**ESTHETIC **%** **$** **#** **-** **&**"
Заголовки могут содержать в себе разные символы, по этому я в 1 строку для примера их поместил.

Это пример уже после слов имеет символы какие "-" и "&" выводятся не корректно на front-end сайта, а именно вот так "&#8211 ;" и  "&#038 ;" это два символа "-" и "&" я пробел перед ";" поставил чтоб наглядно было видно что получаю.

Вот мой код:

```
 $str = get_the_title();
        $array = explode(' ', $str);

        foreach ($array as $k => $value): 
            
            print('<span>' . substr($value, 0, 1) . "</span>" . substr($value, 1) . " ");     

         endforeach;
```

Если сделать var_dump($array) переменой то выходит нормальный массив где каждое слово/символ уже по пробелам разбито.

ARRAY ( [0] => JETPEEL™ [1] => MEDICAL [2] => AESTHETIC [3] => % [4] => $ [5] => # [6] => – [7] => & )

Тот самый код если заменить получение заголовка статьи get_the_title() на строку сразу "JETPEEL™ MEDICAL AESTHETIC % $ # - &" то код все отображает и выводит коректно.

```
 $str =  "JETPEEL™ MEDICAL AESTHETIC % $ # - &"  //get_the_title();
            $array = explode(' ', $str);
    
            foreach ($array as $k => $value): 
                
                print('<span>' . substr($value, 0, 1) . "</span>" . substr($value, 1) . " ");     
    
             endforeach;
```

Я в тупике почему получение заголовков с такими символами выводит не коректно.

Comment: Ваш второй пример кода у меня отработал корректно (только в первой строке добавила в конце точку с запятой, у вас она попала в комментарий), все символы вывелись правильно

Comment: @alenkins так второй и пример был что тот же самый текст если  брать не из переменой какой пришел, а вставить сразу в код то все хорошо. А тот текст какой пришел из переменой get_the_title() то выводятся не коректно спец. символы. Если просто взять вывести сразу из get_the_title() то все коректно работает, А так как мне надо 1 символ всегда выдергивать из троки то не работает код

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `html_entity_decode()`

```
print( html_entity_decode( '<span>' . substr($value, 0, 1) . "</span>" . substr($value, 1) . " " ) );
```

Comment: К  сожалению это не помогает мне, я это тоже пробовал. Если у вас есть стороння песочница для тестирования, буду вам признателен если мой код затестите и может выйдет у вас повторить мою ошибку и решить ее.

Comment: Если просто получить заголовок и вывести, пробелм нету, а вот если разделить первый символк оборачивать в <span> то такая беда

Answer (score -1):

get_the_title() рекомендуется очищать перед выводом на экран, потому что она выводит все HTML теги как есть. Попробуйте использовать

```php
    echo esc_html( get_the_title() );
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает это.